# Does my database save my data or not?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

Im using sql database and making a program with vb. i use this code for my data to save to database:

```
DerslerTableAdapter.Insert(CDate(Me.Label15.Text), Me.Label9.Text)
DerslerTableAdapter.Fill(Verilerim.Dersler)
```

i stop the program. Then run it again. I can see the data i saved, its ok. but i cant see it when i look `"database explorer"->"tables"->"dersler"->"show table data"`.

when i run the program again i can see my data ok. then i save my project and run it again. There is no data. Icant see it. Does the program runs properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TableAdapter.fill() executes the query, so I believe that you need to use TableAdapter.update() to commit the changes to your datebase. Overall I would like to see more code to get a feel for what is going on.

Comment: I add the code you advised:DerslerTableAdapter.Update(Verilerim.Dersler) but nothing changed

Comment: Without seeing all of the code for the TableAdapter, I am guessing. But if you are doing a fill after an insert, the fill is clearing the table unless you set the "clearBeforeFill" to false. So I would do the fill, then the insert, then the update and see if that fixes this.

Comment: thanks a lot. I think the problem is on compiling. If i dont save my project, my data doesnt lose. while saving my project, vb updates something and it causes the data lost. I copied the debug folder, on my desktop and run the exe file, nothing lost.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not committing your changes to the database.